# Should I custom code drop down menus or use a wordpress plugin?

Tags: menus, dropdown, sub-menu

**EDIT** -- Hopefully my question is more clear

What is the best practice for wordpress dropdown menus:

1. Custom CSS (editing styles.css)
2. Using a WP Plugin

I'm leaning toward coding it myself from scratch, but I don't want to reinvent the wheel if there's a plugin that is standard.

Comment: why the down vote?  did I break a stack exchange rule I don't know about?

Comment: I didn't downvote you but your question is not clear and might be closed. A dropdown plugin will use CSS so what exactly are you asking?

Comment: I edited again - is it clear what I'm asking yet?

Comment: You should describe what exactly your understanding of _drop down menu_ is. Best would be a screenshot.

Comment: I didn't realize that was unclear - sorry about that.  I mentioned hover menus in my first question but was told that wasn't clear either.. lose-lose I guess.  I'm closing the question... tough-crowd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would do the code from scratch method, rather than get a plugin and have to reverse engineer it to do it exactly the way you want it to work anyway. CSS is defiantly the way to go and the web standard as opposed to jQuery/java, by my understanding at least.

Comment: exactly what I did - using CSS to style.  Basically, using absolute positioning to have the menu begin way off the screen, and then repositioning on li:hover -- it took a while to figure out the padding for maximum usability, but it's working great.